# HTML-Ajax : form with only submit

Tags: javascript, html

I have a button and when the user clicked on this button, data are modified in the database.

What is the more secure between these 2 solutions :

```
<button id="the_button"> click me </button>

$("#the_button").on("click",function(){
    // send a character to server with Ajax
};
```

or

```
<form method="POST" action="/theurl">
    <input type="submit" value="click me" id="the_button">
</form>
```

In finally, I have just one button.

Comment: Neither method is more secure than the other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### First sample

The difference is the way you are writing it.

The first way allow you to separate the content form the logic, so if you decide to have a different behavior tomorrow you simply modifying your JS and do not have to touch the HTML.

This way you can re-use the HTML in many different parts of your application

---

#### Second

In the second sample you have restricted your self to have the same function being called every time you use this html (in a template for example) and you cant modify it

Comment: But the first sample is more secure that the second no ?

Comment: It has nothing to do with security. the result will be the same, its just a better way to separate the view (html) from the logic (html).

If you decide to change the HTML some day you dont have to change the JS as well

Comment: Ok thank you, In the beggining I was afraid that the solution with Ajax is less secure than the submit form.

Comment: it has nothing to do with security. :-)

Answer (score 1):

There's no "best" answer. They are two different approaches.

Your second option will result in loading a *whole new page*, while your first option uses AJAX to exchange data with the server, then change only some of the information on the page, *without* changing the whole page. Your first option is used commonly in single page applications to change things on the page without sending the user to a new page, or without reloading the page.

So, which behavior do you want? Do you want to reload the page, or send the user to "/theurl", or do you want to change some information on the page without a reload?

Comment: On click on the button, the user like a object. So I want on click my server save this "like". When the server save this "like", just one div is changed.